# Как в массиве зеркально отразить строки относительно горизонтальной оси симметрии?

Tags: java, массивы

В интернете ничего толкового не нашла, хочу понять как именно это делается. Вот программа с самим массивом.

```
class з4 {
  public static void main (String[] args){
    int[][] a=new int[4][5];
    for (int i=0;i < a.length;i++){
      for (int j=0;j < a[i].length;j++){
        a[i][j]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
      }
    }
    for (int i=0;i < a.length;i++,System.out.println()){
      for (int j=0;j < a[i].length;j++){
        System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оптимально так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; ++i)
{
    int tmp[] = a[i];
    a[i] = a[a.length - i - 1];
    a[a.length - i - 1] = tmp;
}
```

Впрочем, если хочется посложнее или надо сильно экономить память, то можно так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; ++j)
    {
         int tmp = a[i][j];
         a[i][j] = a[a.length - i - 1][j];
         a[a.length - i - 1][j] = tmp;
    }
```

P.S. Вообще-то не уверен, что во втором варианте будет экономия памяти. Компилятор в первом варианте может просто ссылки переставить.

**Update**

ТС, я сегодня добрый. Да простит меня сообщество... Держите код:

```
class Test4 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // Инициализация матрицы.
        int[][] a = new int[4][5];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
           for (int j=0; j < a[i].length; j++)
            a[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*10);

        // Вывод исходной матрицы
        for (int i=0;i < a.length;i++,System.out.println())
          for (int j=0;j < a[i].length;j++)
            System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");

        // Трансформация матрицы.
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; ++i) {
            int tmp[] = a[i];
            a[i] = a[a.length - i - 1];
            a[a.length - i - 1] = tmp;
        }

        // Вывод изменённой матрицы.
        System.out.println();
        for (int i=0;i < a.length;i++,System.out.println())
          for (int j=0;j < a[i].length;j++)
            System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: У Вас `a[i]` вне цикла по `i` используется. Т.к. массив прямоугольный то можно `int tmp[] = new int[a[0].length];`

Comment: А в какую именно строчку вставить этот код?

Comment: @Анжелика, оформить отдельным методом класса.

Comment: @andy.37 спасибо!

Comment: Вариант 1: `tmp` не нужна снаружи цикла, и память под нее распределять не надо. `a[a.length - i - 1] = tmp;`

Comment: @andy.37 1) Упс... Копипаст. 2) Массив прямоугольный, можно брать и `a[0]`. Но `a[i]` более универсально, можно работать с двумерными массивами, у которых строки разной длины.

Comment: @Igor Да. Спасибо. Поправил.

Comment: @kff - Увидел. Проголосовал.

Comment: @kff То есть, мне сейчас нужно создать новый класс, в нем сделать импорт класса с кодом массива и вставить Ваш код, правильно?

Comment: @Анжелика Зачем? После вывода исходной матрицы вставляете код отражения и снова вывод. В консоли будут две матрицы - начальная и трасформированная.

Comment: @kff я работаю в эклипсе, и он предлагает мне переименовать i, я соглашаюсь, запускаю программу, но выводится только 1 матрица(

Comment: @Анжелика Не знаю, чего там хочет *Eclipse*. Я уже пару лет на *IntelliJ IDEA*. Я это вообще в *Notepad++* набрал.

Comment: @kff спасибо Вам огромное!

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0; i<a.length/2; i++) {
   int top = i;
   int bottom = a.length - top - 1;
   for (int j=0; j<a[i].length; j++) {
      int temp = a[top][j];
      a[top][j] = a[bottom][j];
      a[bottom][j] = temp;
   }
}
```

Ничего другого в голову не приходит.